# Magento add validations to telephone number in admin panel

Tags: php, validation, magento, admin

I need to add validations to the customer telephone number in admin panel customer add/edit form. I need to accept 10 numbers only. Can anyone help me to do this please. I went through the internet but I did not find any proper/ correct answer.

Thank You.

Comment: Show you attempt please, "I did not find an already chewed up solution for me" won't be considered a sufficient effort from your part by many.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: Your question to ask for help without providing any evidence of what you're doing, or have tried is not really meant for this website, and should be deleted or closed.

Answer (score 0):

Create a js file or add below content to **js/prototype/validation.js** File

```
Validation.add('validate-mobile', 'Please enter a valid mobile number.', function(v) {
    return Validation.get('IsEmpty').test(v) || /^[0-9]{1,10}$/i.test(v)
})
```

If you created js file then add your js file into admin layout files.

and Add "validate-mobile" class to your input field.